# Problem with library g4f at pythonanywhere

Tags: python, aiogram

I encountered a problem with the library (g4f) while executing the code:

```
python
async def GPT_Request(prompt: str) -> str:
    global me
    print(prompt)
    response_generator = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
        model=g4f.models.gpt_4,
        provider=g4f.Provider.Bing,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )
    print(response_generator)
    return response_generator
```

The error returned is:

```
Using Bing provider and gpt-4 model
INFO:aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging:Process update [ID:173124119]: [failed] (in 197 ms)
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-10' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=RuntimeError('Response: ')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/g4f/Provider/bing/conversation.py", line 52, in create_conversation
    data = await response.json()
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1104, in json
    raise ContentTypeError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: ', url=URL('https://www.bing.com/turing/conversation/create?bundleVersion=1.1579.2')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/SYSorarBOT/telegbot.py", line 1980, in bot_message
    response_text = await GPT_Request(message.text)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/SYSorarBOT/telegbot.py", line 42, in GPT_Request
    response_generator = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/g4f/providers/base_provider.py", line 232, in create_async
    return "".join([
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/g4f/providers/base_provider.py", line 232, in <listcomp>
    return "".join([
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/g4f/Provider/Bing.py", line 291, in stream_generate
    conversation = await create_conversation(session)
  File "/home/SiriyiuS/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/g4f/Provider/bing/conversation.py", line 54, in create_conversation
    raise RuntimeError(f"Response: {await response.text()}")
RuntimeError: Response:
```

I am using PythonAnywhere.com as the server.

I tried to set up a proxy_server or to change the addressing method, but this did not help either.

Comment: See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RequestingAllowlistAdditions/

Comment: I have paid to remove this limitation, the problem is that from (pythonanywhere) the request is transmitted differently

Comment: How are you executing this code on PythonAnywhere?  Mind that async code would not work on default web apps.